# Build Error For cv2.imshow()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Was using opencv to capture a preexisting video. The video pops up on a frame 
 buts ends in the following error:

```
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:312: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

My code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('lol.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

PS: I do have ffmpeg in windows and environment path set to it.

Comment: Funny how this question pops up on daily basis. Both `cv2.VideoCapture` constructor, as well as the `read` function can fail. Your code doesn't account for that, `frame` ends up containing an empty image, and then you try to display that empty image, which is not allowed.

Comment: I actually had to use the try:Exception method to overlook the error. But thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: True. What I meant is that you can test the value of `ret`, and when it's `False` break out of the loop, thus preventing this situation from occurring in the first place. The problem is that `isOpened` is true even when you reach the end of the file.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you!